# jquery div collapse/expand in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have jquery code

```
$("a.tabs").click(function (e) {
   var $groupName = $(this).data("group");
    $("[data-group='" + $groupName + "']").each(function () {
      $($(this).data("target")).addClass('collapse').removeClass("in");
    });
});
```

Which expand div and collapse others:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div>
            <div>
                <a data-target="#fm1" class="tabs" data-group="footer-blocks" data-toggle="collapse">Link1</a>
            </div>
            <div id="fm1" class="collapse show-in-md">
                Link1 content     
            </div>
   </div>

    <div>
            <div>
                <a data-target="#fm2" class="tabs" data-group="footer-blocks" data-toggle="collapse">Link2</a>
            </div>
            <div id="fm2" class="collapse show-in-md">
                Link2 content     
            </div>
   </div>

    <div>
            <div>
                <a data-target="#fm3" class="tabs" data-group="footer-blocks" data-toggle="collapse">Link3</a>
            </div>
            <div id="fm3" class="collapse show-in-md">
                Link3 content     
            </div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Problem, when I click on the anchor and it expand the div it wont collapse if I click it again. Could you give me some tip how to fix the jquery code. I know it's something simple but I've tried couple of things and I can't get it done.

Here you can find working example: http://www.bootply.com/JdX7qe6QkG

And, yes I know that is bootstrap and I could use accordian classes, etc. but I want to do it other way.

Thank you

Comment: You would need to do the reverse of what you did when clicking... ie. if you removed a class on click (the first time), the you need to add it back when you click again... does that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my take on it:

Change you class removal to this

`$(this).data("target").toggleClass('collapse').toggleClass("in");`

it will switch back and forth between the classes to show/collapse the targets

**UPDATED**

If item is expanded, clicking on it again will collapse it.  All non-clicked items will be collapsed too.

```js
$(function() {
  $("a.tabs").click(function(e) {
    var target = $(this).data("target");
    var isTargetExpanded = $(target).hasClass('in');
    $('.show-in-md').addClass('collapse').removeClass('in'); // collapse all before expading clicked target

    if (isTargetExpanded) {
      $(target).addClass('collapse').removeClass("in"); // collapse clicked target
    } else {
      $(target).removeClass('collapse').addClass("in"); // expand clicked target
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.tabs {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #4a4a4a;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  color: #fff;
}
.tabs:hover {
  color: #aaa;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div>
      <div>
        <a data-target="#fm1" class="tabs" data-group="footer-blocks" data-toggle="collapse">Link1</a>
      </div>
      <div id="fm1" class="collapse show-in-md">
        Link1 content
      </div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <div>
        <a data-target="#fm2" class="tabs" data-group="footer-blocks" data-toggle="collapse">Link2</a>
      </div>
      <div id="fm2" class="collapse show-in-md">
        Link2 content
      </div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <div>
        <a data-target="#fm3" class="tabs" data-group="footer-blocks" data-toggle="collapse">Link3</a>
      </div>
      <div id="fm3" class="collapse show-in-md">
        Link3 content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, but I need to collapse other div's and expand clicked one AND also collapse the expanded div when "LinkX" is clicked.

Comment: I accept this answer because it's an alternative for my solution (below) and I like what you did with `isTargetExpanded` :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$("a.tabs").click(function (e) {
    var $groupName = $(this).data("group"),
        targetDiv = $($(this).data('target'));

    $(this).closest(".collapsible-container").find(".collapsible").not(targetDiv).addClass('collapse');
    $(targetDiv).toggleClass('collapse');
});
```

And add another class to identify collapsible divs easily, like this:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row collapsible-container">
    <div>
        <div>
            <a data-target="#fm1" class="tabs" data-group="footer-blocks" data-toggle="collapse">Link1</a>
        </div>
        <div id="fm1" class="collapsible collapse show-in-md">
            Link1 content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <a data-target="#fm2" class="tabs" data-group="footer-blocks" data-toggle="collapse">Link2</a>
        </div>
        <div id="fm2" class="collapsible collapse show-in-md">
            Link2 content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div> <a data-target="#fm3" class="tabs" data-group="footer-blocks" data-toggle="collapse">Link3</a>
        </div>
        <div id="fm3" class="collapsible collapse show-in-md">
            Link3 content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Check fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tyn97xrz/2/)

Comment: Your solution works but I think there will be problem if I will have this collapsible divs for example in footer and other in content. I think there should be more `this` used because I want use one script across whole webpage and only change `data-group` and `data-target` in HTML.

Comment: Check the updated code. I've added a `collapsible-container` class to the parent. You can use this class to group collapsible divs.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got it (HTML with no changes):

```
$("a.tabs").click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $groupName = $(this).data("group");
  var $this = $(this);
  $("[data-group='"+ $groupName +"']:not([data-target='" + $this.data("target") + "'])").each(function () {
    $($(this).data("target")).removeClass("in").addClass('collapse');
  });
});
```

Example: http://www.bootply.com/EPbRaKhVtB

Do you think this is cleanest as can be? Maybe you would improve it?
Thank you.

Comment: you can see my updated answer - no looping necessary :)